# SSRS Chrome/IE Error

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

We are having issues loading our report server in both IE and Chrome; for some reason, it only works properly in Firefox.

When we try to load it in Chrome, we receive this error:

This webpage is not available

Hide details
The webpage at http://database/reports might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error code: ERR_INVALID_AUTH_CREDENTIALS

When we try to load it in IE, it circles through the authentication page three times and just dies.

Thanks to anyone with any insight!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that SSO is failing and you might need to register an SPN for your SSRS server:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281382.aspx